# php cors issue with axios post

Tags: php, cors, axios

I have a simple post request with axios to php script which renders some pdfs and should return a String.

Now I got this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'IP:7580/pdfgen/pdfGen.php' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I set this in my php file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

With no changes. also tried this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With");
```

also no changes.

my axios call looks like this:

```
axios.post("http://IP:7580/pdfgen/pdfGen.php", this.state)
        .then(response => {
            report = {...this.state.report};
            report.createdAt = reportCreatedAt;

            window.open(response.data);


            this.setState({report: report, pdf: response.data});
            console.log(response);
        })
```

What could solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may have to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the `php.ini` file and restart web server for this to work .. I've had issues in the past with attempting to allow with the `header` tag ..  Simply because you have to allow it at a high enough level that all your includes/requires are also "allowed"

Comment: how should it look like in php.ini?

Comment: I was mistaken -- I had to allow it on the server-side  ---  If you are using Apache .. You can use the .htaccess file or vHost config to allow ..  Adding `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to the file ..  Then you have to make sure that headers is enabled `a2enmod headers` then restart ..

Comment: @Zak — PHP programs *do* run server side. There shouldn't be any need to involve apache or php configuration editing.

Comment: My setup must be different then ..  I had to do the following: https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html   --  Does it not have to pass the web **server** to get to the php **module** ?

Comment: @Zak — The web server passes it through to PHP freely and automatically. https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Comment: @Felix — Is the PHP script running at all when the OPTIONS request is made? (e.g. is there some PHP you aren't showing us which does something clever with routing do that only POST requests are hitting your `header()` statements?)

Comment: @Quentin script is not running at all. It is running when its called via the axios post request from frontend. No there is no routing in php. its a simple stupid php scirpt that only collects the '$_POST' and does some simple stuff with pfd and stores it.

Comment: @Zak already added those stuff to `.htaccess`

Comment: any further hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A working solution for me is:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    // Decide if the origin in $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] is one
    // you want to allow, and if so:
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```